# FindBug does not detect null from javax.annotation.Nullable method

Tags: java, findbugs, spotbugs

I am not sure if it should but FindBug does not detect error for:

```
public @Nullable String getNull() {
    return null;
}
public @Nonnull String getNotNull() {
    return getNull();
}
public void doSomething() {
    getNull().length();
}
```

It only detects:

```
public @Nonnull String getNotNull() {
    return null;
}
```

but this case is not so helpful as checking for `@Nonnull` return method contract...

I use:

```
import javax.annotation.Nonnull;
import javax.annotation.Nullable;
```

and Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'findbugs'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Section 3.7.2 of the Checker Reference Manual](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#nullness-related-work) explains this (undesirable) behavior:

> 3.7.2  **Incompatibility note about FindBugs @Nullable**
>
> FindBugs has a non-standard definition of @Nullable. FindBugs’s
>   treatment is not documented in its own Javadoc; it is different from
>   the definition of @Nullable in every other tool for nullness analysis;
>   it means the same thing as @NonNull when applied to a formal
>   parameter; and it invariably surprises programmers. Thus, FindBugs’s
>   @Nullable is detrimental rather than useful as documentation. In
>   practice, your best bet is to not rely on FindBugs for nullness
>   analysis, even if you find FindBugs useful for other purposes...
>
> FindBugs suppresses all warnings at uses of a @Nullable variable. (You
>   have to use @CheckForNull to indicate a nullable variable that
>   FindBugs should check.)...

```
// declare getObject() to possibly return null
@Nullable Object getObject() { ... }

void myMethod() {
   @Nullable Object o = getObject();
   // FindBugs issues no warning about calling toString on a possibly-null reference!
   o.toString();
}
```

> ...With FindBugs, you annotate a declaration, which suppresses checking
>   at all client uses, even the places that you want to check.